# Windows Phone 8 + PhoneGap + Crafty = Gray Shading

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, craftyjs

I'm trying to create a small game in WP8 and PhoneGap, and wanted to use the Crafty (CraftyJS) library.

The game seems to be loading correctly (graphics and logic seems fine), but whenever I press anywhere on the screen (both in the Emulator and in a Device), I'm seeing a gray shading.

I thought this kind of behavior was resolved in WP8.

Anyone has experience with CraftyJS in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting Windows Phone 8? The Grey shading issue existed in Windows Phone 7 but was removed from IE10/WP8

Comment: I'm targeting WP8 for certain (had to go back and make sure ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gray highlight feature can now be disabled using:

```
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
```

You should take a look at [this article](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx) for more tips